# Does it make any sense to have "sound" and "design" as tags for a site named "sound design"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm new, browsing the tags of the site.
I felt that many (80%?) tags are not documented, and a great many are rather poor choices (IMHO).

Comment: Hi U. Windl. As for the blank tags, I've actually recently started creating usage guidance excerpts for popular tags, as we do have a lot without usage guidance and/or description.